# Mongodb C# driver issues in multi-threaded application

Tags: c#, mongodb, driver

The C# driver seems to timeout or hang on a call to FindAsync() after many calls.
I've tried recreating the MongoClient or deregistering the associated cluster to no effect.  The driver just hangs after a while in a multi-threaded/task application.

Has anyone experienced this and found a solution?

Comment: Do you create `new MongoClient` with each request?

Comment: Using a singleton instance. Recreating the singleton while the application is running doesn't seem to have an effect.

Comment: Figured out my issue.  I had one query without a backing index in the database that was never returning.  It seemed to cause other concurrent queries on other collections to stall.